# How to add relative paths and how to mount volumes in a container with Podman

Tags: python, podman

I'd like to build a container using Podman which would contains the following:

- a Python application
- the Python modules I developed but which are not stored at the same place than the Python application
- the Python environment (made with miniconda/mambaforge)
- a mounted folder for input data
- a mounted folder for output data

To do that, I've added a Dockerfile in my home directory. I had to put the Dockerfile at a such high path level because it seems that it needs to be above any folder I want to add in the container. Indeed, I've tried to add folders using rising path with "../../some/path/" but it doesn't work. Then, a first question is: **Is there a solution to add folders which are not below (in path) the Dockerfile?**

Below is the content of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# Add the Python application
ADD /path/to/my_python_app /my_python_app

# Add the Python modules used by the Python application
ADD /path/to/my_modules /my_modules

# Add the whole mambaforge folder (contains the virtual envs) with the exact same path than the local one
ADD /path/to/mambaforge /exact/same/path/to/mambaforge

# Create a customized .bashrc (contains 'export PATH' to add mamba path and 'export PYTHONPATH' to add my_modules path)
ADD Dockerfile_bashrc /root/.bashrc
```

Then, I build the container with:

```
podman build -t python_app .
```

And run it with:

```
podman run -i -t python_app -v /path/to/input/data:/mnt/input -v /path/to/output/data:/mnt/output /bin/bash
```

The container runs correctly and I can execute my Python application into. However, the volumes do not appear in /mnt. A second question is: **How to mount volumes in a container?** I've tried with '--volume' and '--mount', with '/path/to/input/data:/mnt/input:z' and '/path/to/input/data:/mnt/input:Z', but nothing works.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The order of the arguments is not correct. `podman run -i -t python_app -v /path/to/input/data:/mnt/input -v /path/to/output/data:/mnt/output /bin/bash`. The option `-v` needs to come before the image name

Comment: Not allowing _ADD ../some/path/_  is due to security reasons. There are pros and cons. The risk when building a Dockerfile from an unknown source will be reduced.

Comment: Many thanks @ErikSjölund! I'm reducing the initial post and I'll add the solution. I'll separate the other questions in another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions were given in comments. Here is a summary:

**Is there a solution to add folders which are not below (in path) the Dockerfile?** No, not allowing ADD ../some/path/ is due to security reasons.

**How to mount volumes in a container?** The order of the arguments was not correct. The option `-v` needs to come before the image name. The following command works fine:

```
podman run -i -t -v /path/to/input/data:/mnt/input -v /path/to/output/data:/mnt/output python_app /bin/bash
```